Meaning of "all"
What does "all" mean in this context?

SUB Newcastle 1-1 Man City (66 mins) It's all Newcastle here and
there's another cross which is begging to be put away. Man City
goalscorer Josko Gvardiol is on hand with a vital interception.


You need to TELL US that this is a TAPE. It's spoken, football English. If I were not a football game watcher, I might not have understood it. Also, where are you getting these recordings?

Can you please close some of these? I have tried to help you several times and the favor is not returned.

SUB Newcastle 1-1 Man City (66 mins) It's all Newcastle here and there's another cross which is begging to be put away. Man City goalscorer Josko Gvardiol is on hand with a vital interception.
This means that Newcastle players are controlling the ball and game at that particular moment of the game.

@MariosAthanasiou There's something wrong re the question you answered. It's not clear to me whether it's spoken or written. And by the way, A noun or verb phrase heading a sentence has no subject at all.  Consider: Wondering about the question, he leaned over his desk and picked up another article.

It means that Newcastle are dominating the game
“All” is, of course hyperbolic, but most of the play on the ball, most of the field position, and most of the attacking moves/shots on goal, are by Newcastle. At least, at the time of the comment - the score is 1-1, so it can’t literally have been all Newcastle all of the time.

Where can I look "all" up in to mean "dominate" in a dictionary?

@Shakila in the middle of the “a” section

Thanks Dale M. Can you explain what 'begging to be put away" meas in the sentence above?

Yes, if you ask that as a new question I can answer it, but I’m not answering in a comment

"begging to be put away" means there is a goal scoring opportunity.
